# GtkLabel use markup while keeping CSS styling

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pango

I have a GtkLabel with which I have setup a hyperlink using the `<a>` tag in the label's markup however doing so negates any styling my GtkCssProvider sets. How can I continue to allow CSS to style the text in the label while also making it a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to style all the text you could try

```
GtkLabel *{
color : red;
}
```

this selects pretty much selects everything in gtk labels(like all states) and applies the css style to all of it.

to Style only the link part select the subnode "link"

```
label link{
color : red;
}
```

Comment: The identifier is actually label not GtkLabel and that works although that's not really ideal. What's the exact state that's being selected? Is there a more fine grained selector than simply using *?

Comment: in the previous version's of gtk GtkLabel is allowed as a selector...and insted of * you can use the subnode "link" to select the link part of the text